# packageInfo.requestedPermissions return incorrect permissions

Tags: android

This is my AndroidManifest.xml, and there are 8 permissions in this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.jiyuzhai.xxxx">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
    <application
        android:name=".main.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
        <activity
            android:name="com.jiyuzhai.xxx.main.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.jiyuzhai.xxx.settings.SetttingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-2905597280622539~7328266239" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Then I use the following code to get permissions in file AndroidManifest.xml,

```
try {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    String[] permissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
    if (permissions == null || permissions.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You did not register any permissions in the manifest.xml.");
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(permissions));
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    throw new AssertionError("Package name cannot be found.");
}
```

but the result was incorrect, I got the following permissions, `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` was missing!!!, why?

[image]

[Edit] Add android sdk version and phone state.

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    minSdkVersion = 17
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you request / approved that "dangerous" permission? If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, and the app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, the user isn't notified of any app permissions at install time. Your app must ask the user to grant the dangerous permissions at runtime.

Comment: I've not faced this before, but maybe it is collapsing those in the same Permission Group since the other will be granted? You can test this by adding some other permissions. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#perm-groups

Answer (score -1):

I think this question has already been answered in this post:

[Storage permission error in Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Permission result callback:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
        //resume tasks needing this permission
    }
}
```

Comment: you misunderstood the question  .

Comment: The problem isn't runtime permissions or access being denied. It is that an incomplete list of permissions is returned by the packageInfo object.